# Fatal error: Call to undefined method Confession::viewConfessionLikes()

Tags: php, html

Hello on my website I have a page which displays the most liked post but when I goes to this page in first post appears this message : `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Confession::viewConfessionLikes() on line 55`

The page not display all the posts but display a link in which when you click redirects to the original post.

Post (confession)

PHP

```
    <?php
class Confession {

private $db;

function __construct($pdo){
    $this->db = $pdo;
}

public function viewConfession($id) {
    $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM secrets WHERE id = :id');
    $this->db->bind(':id', $id);
    return $this->db->single();
}

$secrets = new Confession($pdo);
$confess =& $secrets;
includes_once 'includes/likes.php';
?>
```

HTML

```
<ul class="list-group">

          <?php 
          //GET RESULTS FOR LIKE
          $pdo->query('select t1.* from likes t1 inner join (select `secret_id`, count(*) cnt from likes group by `secret_id`) t2 on t1.`secret_id` = t2.`secret_id` order by t2.cnt desc, t1.`id`');
          $rows_like = $pdo->resultset();

          foreach ($rows_like as $l): 
          $id = $l['secret_id'];
          ?>
          <li class="list-group-item">

              <span class="badge badge-success">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
                  <?php echo $ilike->likes($id); ?>
              </span>

              <span class="label label-success">+1</span>&nbsp;
       -------->>  <a href="secret.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" title=""><?php echo mb_substr($confess->viewConfessionLikes($id), 0, 85); ?>...</a>
          </li>
          <?php endforeach; ?>

</ul>
```

Comment: `$confess =& $secrets;` <-- why assign by reference? If `$secrets` gets reassigned, `$confess` will hold a different value

Comment: `incluses_once` ? it should be `include_once`.

Comment: You never had defined `viewConfessionLikes` in your confession class then how can you call it ??

Comment: I have called them here : <? php echo mb_substr($confess->viewConfessionLikes($id), 0, 85); ?>

Comment: i cant find `viewConfessionLikes` method in your `Confession` class. where is it?

Comment: @mastec2: Yes, we can all see that, my question to you is: Why are you assigning by reference? If `$secrets` is reassigned, then `$confess` will no longer be what you need it to be (ie: it won't be an instance of `Confession`). That and the method name is `viewConfession`, not `viewConfessionLikes`

Comment: also if i put viewConfession instead viewConfessionLikes it not works (these two are the same)

Comment: Maybe elaborate on this a bit... OP clearly didn't include the full code (the `Confession` class doesn't include the closing `}` for example). There is a `viewConfession` method, but we're missing the relevant code to accurately  diagnose the problem

Comment: @mastec2 What is the error when you use `viewConfession`

Comment: Warning: mb_substr() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: Obviously those are two different errors.. Not the same

Comment: the code is that i don't have other code i want to call in html file a partial text of the code in format like a link, i call them by viewConfession but appears : warning mb_substr exc...

Comment: Where the $pdo coming from and what is single method in that that returns an array if you want to return it string you have to handle that

Answer (score 0):

You have define viewConfessionLikes() method in your Confession class as you are getting Fatal error